# Ruby - convert string to model name for where search

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have an array of roles coming from `params`

```
roles = ["Guest", "Admin", "Member"]
```

These roles match my models.

I want to loop through these roles to search the matching models. Like so:

```
roles.each do |role|
  role.where(status: "active")
end
```

I've tried `send` and `to_sym` but my `roles` are not methods, but models. And `role` is not a symbol but a Model.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do this but it's just a part, we don't see where you store the result of your queries

```
roles.each do |role|
  role.constantize.where(status: "active")
end
```

And I also suggest you to check if these roles are only the ones you want to look for, sanitize the input